Error when sending the first message in the chat app
I am currently writing a chat app using react native. In my app, I am trying to show the date lable on the chatScreen of the app. It works totally fine in most of the scenarios, except for the one that after setting up the group chat and send the first message in the group. The below message was shown in the log after sending the first message in the group:
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'sentAt' of undefined

This error is located at:
in ChatScreen (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by MainNavigator)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by KeyboardAvoidingView)
in KeyboardAvoidingView (created by MainNavigator)
in MainNavigator (created by AppNavigator)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppNavigator)
in AppNavigator (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by MenuProvider)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by MenuProvider)
in MenuProvider (created by App)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by App)
in Provider (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

 LOG  Unsubscribing firebase listeners
 ERROR  ReferenceError: Property 'e' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

The below is the code I have written:
const chatMessages = useSelector((state) => {
  if (!chatId) return [];
  const chatMessagesData = state.messages.messagesData[chatId];
  if (!chatMessagesData) return [];
  const messageList = [];
  for (const key in chatMessagesData) {
    const message = chatMessagesData[key];
    messageList.push({
      key,
      ...message,
    });
  }
  return messageList;
});

const sortedChatMessagesData = chatMessages.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let dateGroup = acc.find((x) => x.sentAt === formatDate(item.sentAt));

  if (dateGroup) {
    dateGroup.data.push(item);
  } else {
    acc.push({
      sentAt: formatDate(item.sentAt),
      data: [item],
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

The structure of the chatMessages is as follows:
[
  {
    "key": "abcdefg",
    "readBy": {
      "ABlAcuX4TzNArdXdXL707E98hu63": [Object],
      "sRGDMsKaosZUUeqHto2yQLIe8tE2": [Object]
    },
    "sentAt": "2024-05-28T17:11:34.469Z",
    "sentBy": "sRGDMsKaosZUUeqHto2yQLIe8tE2",
    "text": "Hihi"
  }
]

I think the error is caused by the no initial date label could be set up after the first message is sent. But I cannot figure out how to handle the case at the moment. Anyone has any idea on it?
Thanks in advance!
